# How to Take File Input from User in gmail addon using App script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a Gmail addon where I want to take file input from user like docs, pdf, png etc. I created a function to add a File input button and another function to handle file input but the problem is that the method is depreciated. Here the code:

```
function buildLoginForm1() {
  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder();
  var cardSection = CardService.newCardSection().setHeader('Login 1');

  var fileInput = CardService.newDecoratedText()
    .setText('Choose a file')
    .setButton(CardService.newTextButton()
      .setText('Choose file')
      .setOnClickAction(CardService.newAction()
        .setFunctionName('onFilePicker')));

  cardSection.addWidget(fileInput);

  card.addSection(cardSection);

  return card.build();

}
```

So in Above function I have made a custom File input box to Take file input from user. Now to handle the file input I created a function like this

```
function onFilePicker(e) {
  var action = CardService.newAction();
  action.setFunctionName('handleFileSelection');

  var filePicker = CardService.newFileChooser()
      .setMimeType(CardService.MimeType.ALL)
      .setMode(CardService.FilePickerMode.OVERLAY)
      .setOnSelectionAction(action);

  var card = CardService.newCardBuilder()
      .addSection(CardService.newCardSection()
          .addWidget(filePicker))
      .build();

  var navigation = CardService.newNavigation()
      .pushCard(card);

  return CardService.newActionResponseBuilder()
      .setNavigation(navigation)
      .build();
}
```

But the error is that addon is saying

`TypeError: Cannot find function newFileChooser in object CardService. [line: 64, function: onFilePicker, file: Code]`

Is there any way to take file input from user in Gmail addon using Appscript or is it not possible to take file input from user.